# How to close a new window in macOS development?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to macOS application development.
I have a main window and a custom window called ImageSetter, both have windowcontroller. 
In the main window, I have a button, whose action is to open a new window by:

```
ImageSetter *anImageSetter = [[ImageSetter alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ImageSetter"];
    [anImageSetter showWindow:self];
```

On the window of ImageSetter, I want to attach a button, whose function is to close the ImageSetter window. I tried to use

```
[aButton setTarget:self];
[aButton setAction:@selector(closeItself)];
```

and

```
- (void)closeItself{
  [self.window close];
}
```

in the implementation of ImageSetter.
But I figured that I can't close it by using that button.
Help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a standard window already has a button to close it in the title bar. If at all possible, you should use the standard controls.

If you have a button in a window, and all you want that button to do is close its window, simply send the `performClose:` message up the responder chain:

```
// [aButton setTarget:nil/* first responder */]; -- already nil, nothing to set
[aButton setAction:@selector(performClose:)];
```

The button will send the `-performClose:` message to the first object in the responder chain that implements to that message, which in your case should be the window that contains the button.

If you want to be explicit about the target, you can set it directly:

```
[aButton setTarget:aButton.window];
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much!

Comment: `[aButton setTarget:self]` doesn't send the message to the button, since `self` is presumably not the same as `aButton`. Probably, this code was in the window controller, so it was sending it to that controller.

Comment: Good point, I wasn't thinking about the context. The pitfall of code fragments... I'll remove that from the answer.